# Get ArcGIS Pro Portal user

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, user-account

I'm trying to get the user I used to login to Portal in ArcGIS Pro, but I can't find how. Is it possible?

I manage to fetch the Portal information using

```
arcpy.GetPortalDescription()
```

, but not the user used to login in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some reason this was not working:

```
portal_desc = arcpy.GetPortalDescription()
portalUser = portal_desc["user"]["username"]
```

Now, it is. Don't mind this question